# iOS Device - iOS Device HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ios

I am trying to create an app where one device will stream live video to another device. From what I've read, HTTP Live Streaming is to download videos that are already in .m3u8 format. So that doesn't work and it doesn't look like there are any easy ways to do this.

I'm guessing that I'll have to use AVCapture to capture each frame and then upload each frame to a server. The other device will then download each frame. But that will be ridiculously slow.

Is there any sample code or tutorial which will be helpful ?

Thanks

Comment: Not yet. There's a temporary fix by using OpenTok though